# What is are the different ways to deal with plural values using Javascript and how to support localization?

Tags: javascript, json, api, localization

// Example response from API

"period": {
            "periodIn": "days",
            "periodValue": 10 
        }

So, In front-end it results to `10 days`. // But, if the periodValue was 1 then my result would be `1 days`, which is not correct.

I know back-end is not handling data properly but I think there should be way to handle this situation in front-end.

I want to know what is the proper way to deal with this sort of situation. I currently don't use any localization library but I have my own JSON file where I store all the data as placeholders that I get from response.

Looking forward to hear from you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, you could store the various words and their singilar and plural type and get a function for the word an anpther for getting the formatted string.

If you have different formatting, you could store the format along with the words.

```js
function getPlural(number, word) {
    return number === 1 ? word.one : word.other;
}

function getValue(v, word) {
    return `${v} ${getPlural(v, words[word])}`;
}

var words = {
        day: { one: 'day', other: 'days' }
    };

console.log(getValue(1, 'day'));
console.log(getValue(7, 'day'));
console.log(getValue(0, 'day'));
```

Comment: Hey @Nina Scholz thank you so much. This was preliminary technique I had been provided by my colleague. I was having hard time to get the bits and pieces together. Thank you for sharing your solution. It works like a charm. You are awesome.